# How to load html file inside jquery plugin in angular js

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I am using one jquery plugin for DYO(Design your own). Inside the js file of that plugin it had loaded one template file as shown below

```
 $.post(options.templatesDirectory + 'productdesigner.php',
        options.labels,
        function (html) {
            debugger;

            $elem.append($.parseHTML(html));

            $fullLoader = $elem.children('.fpd-full-loader').hide();
            $mainContainer = $elem.children('.fpd-main-container');
            $productStage = $mainContainer.children('.fpd-product-stage').height(options.stageHeight);

            $elementTooltip = $productStage.children('.fpd-element-tooltip').html(options.labels.outOfContainmentAlert);
            $mainContainer.children('.fpd-context-dialog').remove().clone().prependTo($sidePanel);
            $contextDialog = $body.find('.fpd-context-dialog').addClass('fpd-hidden');
            $contextLoader = $contextDialog.find('.fpd-context-loader');
            $colorPicker = $contextDialog.find('.fpd-color-picker');
            $colorPicker1 = $contextDialog.find('.fpd-color-pickerrr');
            $swatchPicker = $contextDialog.find('.fpd-color-swatch');

            $elem.trigger('templateLoad', [this.url]);
            setTimeout(_initBars, 1000);
        }
    );
```

I am trying to integrate that plugin to angularJS. How can I load this HTML file in this plugin. I just need a path to load this HTML file in angularjs. I tried giving path but it is always returning 404 not found error.

Comment: can you show your angular code?

Comment: i have just loaded this plugin through angular in index.html file. I just need to load that file which i mentioned above in plugin js file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out it my self. I loaded the template in the plugin using jquery load() method as shown below.

```
 var $div = $('<div>');

  $div.load('modules/dyo/views/test.html', function(){
    var html=this;
    $elem.append(html);
    $fullLoader = $elem.children().children('.fpd-full-loader').hide();
    $mainContainer = $elem.children().children('.fpd-main-container');
    $productStage = $mainContainer.children('.fpd-product-stage').height(options.stageHeight);

    $elementTooltip = $productStage.children('.fpd-element-tooltip').html(options.labels.outOfContainmentAlert);
    $mainContainer.children('.fpd-context-dialog').remove().clone().prependTo($sidePanel);
    $contextDialog = $body.find('.fpd-context-dialog').addClass('fpd-hidden');
    $contextLoader = $contextDialog.find('.fpd-context-loader');
    $colorPicker = $contextDialog.find('.fpd-color-picker');
    $colorPicker1 = $contextDialog.find('.fpd-color-pickerrr');
    $swatchPicker = $contextDialog.find('.fpd-color-swatch');
    $elem.trigger('templateLoad', [this.url]);

  });
```